# Reading a text file into a hashTable

Tags: c, io, binary, hashtable, read-write

I have a hashTable and I have been trying to Read key/data pairs into it from a text file. When i read it in it appears to have been read in correctly but when i print the contents only the last entry in the textfile is being printed at every index of the table. Here is my readFile, saveFile functions:

```
int readFile(char * fileName, HTable * hashTable){
char *key = malloc(sizeof(char*));
char *data = malloc(sizeof(char*));
int eof;
//char buf[50];

//Create file pointer and point it at fild to open
FILE * fp;
fp = fopen(fileName, "rb+");

//check if file exists
if(!fp){
    printf("File could not be opened\n");
    return 0;
}

//Set a temp Node to hold data, read data into the temp Node
//and insert temp into hashtable
printf("Here we go\n");

while(1){
    eof = fscanf(fp, "%s %s", key, data);
    if(EOF == eof)
        break;

    //fgets(buf, 50, fp);                                   
    //sscanf(buf, "%s %s", key, data);
    insertData(hashTable, key, data);
    printf("Index %d: %s %s\n\n", hashTable->hashFunction(hashTable- 
            >size, key), key, data);

}

//Close file pointer
fclose(fp);

return 1;
}

void saveFile(char * fileName, HTable * hashTable){
//Create a FILE pointer and point it to the file to open or create
FILE * fp;
fp = fopen(fileName, "wb+");

//If the file does not exist or cannot be created give error message
if(!fp){
    printf("ERROR: File could not be created\n");
    return;
}


//for each index of the hashTable write its contents to the file
for(int i = 0; i < hashTable->size; i++){
    Node * temp = hashTable->table[i];
    while(temp != NULL){
        fprintf(fp, "%s %s \n", temp->key, temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
        printf("saved....\n");
    }
    printf("Index %d saved\n", i);
}

//Close file pointer
fclose(fp);

}
```

And my output when i try to read the file:

// This is the output from the readFile telling me where the data has gone

Index: 1
Index 1: Facebook sjfl253sFace

Index: 2
Index 2: Gmail 343728Gamil

Index: 3
Index 3: Insta alsdhfishInsta

// This is the output from my main
Index 1: Insta alsdhfishInsta
Index 2: Insta alsdhfishInsta
Index 3: Insta alsdhfishInsta

// This is the end of main when i delete the hashTable
// It stops at 2 and gives me a malloc error
Completed deletion of index 1 of 5
Completed deletion of index 2 of 5

Comment: Okay well i figured this out literally right after i posted, it wasnt working because i wasnt using strcpy before inserting it into my hashtable, BUT i have no idea why i need to do that, the Node data is void so that might have something to do with it. If anyone knows the answer would be very much appreciated

Comment: You are probably overwriting the same buffer with new data, while only storing pointers in the hashtable.

Comment: `char *key = malloc(sizeof(char*));
char *data = malloc(sizeof(char*));` You are allocating enough space for **two pointers** here. You need space for the **actual strings**